# The project has an older format and will be converted

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

Android studio keeps telling me project is in old format even though I already have it converted (2 times actually - now it says the backup will be stored in *projectFilesBackup3*). 
Clicking *details* reveals this:

> RunConfigurations of type JUnitConfiguration will be converted to
>   AndroidJUnitConfiguration. JUnit tests and Android Instrumented tests
>   will work properly together.

It works but is just inconvenient. What is interesting is that all those backup directories are empty.
Still, how do I resolve this permanently?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this annoyance? It is happening to me many times a day when I switch between projects.

Comment: so far, no, as it seemed to cease after upgrade, so I just gave up. But it occured to me a few days ago with one before the newest version, so perhaps I'll look into this (but don't promise)